# Allure report clean in @Wdio in webdriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io, allure, wdio-v4, wdio-v5

I am able to create allure report and open it. But I could not clean the previous results. I tried with the official document which does not give expected results.

Comment: Try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822720/remove-tests-that-were-not-executed-from-allure-report/48976667#48976667

Answer (score 3):

I really like using **[rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf)** for this job. Never disappointed me... yet!

1. Install package and save as project dependency:

`npm install --save-dev rimraf@latest`

2. In your `package.json` file, add the following [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts):

---

```
  "scripts": {
    "report-open": "allure open allure-report",
    "report-generate": "allure generate --clean allure-results",
    "pretest": "rimraf allure-results && rimraf allure-report && rimraf test-screenshots && rimraf wdio-logs"
  },
```

**Usage:**

- **pre-test:** in order to start clean, run `npm run-script pretest` (*will remove all Allure results/reports, along with other mentioned logs & printscreens*)
- **after-test:** run `npm run-script report-generate` (*will generate the Allure report based on `allure-results` folder contents*)
- **inspect report:** run `npm run-script report-open` (*will open the Allure created inside the `allure-report` folder*)

**!Note:** You also have to have [allure-commandline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-commandline) installed globally in order to run the above commands. (`npm install -g allure-commandline@latest`)